# Using shared_ptr in multihtreading code

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

There is a sample code which "works" in a multithreading environment:

```
void CSampleClass::Stop(void) {
  if (m_pDB != nullptr) {
  ... Here is some code
    m_pDB->Interrupt();
  }
}
```

, where the `m_pDB` member is declared as `boost::shared_ptr<CSampleDatabase> m_pDB;`. `m_pDB` can be reset in another class method. That is why it is tested to not `nullptr`. As the code have multiple threads, can be a **situation** when `m_pDB` is reset, by another thread, in between `if (...)` and `m_pDB->Interrupt();`. The result is quite dramatic. To prevent such situation I use the following code modification

```
void CSampleClass::Stop(void) {
  auto pDb = m_pDB; //lock
  if (pDb != nullptr) {
  ... Here is some code
    pDb->Interrupt();
  }
}
```

, i.e. if `m_pDB.reset();` called, the object is never released until `pDb` is destroyed.

The questions are:

1. Is there a "standard" way to prevent the **situation** without involving lockers, mutexes, critical sections, etc.? Something like using `boost::weak_ptr` to break circular references.
2. Is it guaranteed that the compiler declares `pDB` as `boost::shared_ptr<CSampleDatabase>` and not `CSampleDatabase *`? May be it is safer to write `decltype(m_pDB) pDb = m_pDB; //lock`?

Comment: The second version still contains a race condition. Copy-constructing a `shared_ptr` is not an atomic operation.

Comment: @n.m.: From [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety): "shared_ptr objects offer the same level of thread safety as built-in types". This means that it is safe to have multiple `shared_ptr` instances referring to the same object and to modify those `shared_ptr`s concurrently, but it is not safe to concurrently modify/read a single `shared_ptr` instance.

Comment: @Mankarse, read examples bellow. Case like in topic mentioned there and marked as safe

Comment: @Lol4t0 You must be reading a different page than I am. This example is mentioned there (example 4) and it reads: "// writes p3; undefined, simultaneous read/write"

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, yeah, missed that point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution presented is not safe. It is similar to this example from [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety):

```
// thread A
p = p3; // reads p3, writes p

// thread B
p3.reset(); // writes p3; undefined, simultaneous read/write
```

Simultaneous *reads* from the same instance are safe. Any other concurrent operations on the same instance are not.

> Is there a "standard" way to prevent the situation without involving lockers, mutexes, critical sections, etc.? Something like using boost::weak_ptr to break circular references.

You need mutual exclusion, so you need to use a mutual exclusion construct.

> Is it guaranteed that the compiler declares `pDB` as `boost::shared_ptr<CSampleDatabase>` and not `CSampleDatabase *`? May be it is safer to write `decltype(m_pDB) pDb = m_pDB; //lock`?

Yes, `pDB` will be a `shared_ptr`.